# Python Adding Elements to list (append)

Tags: python, windows, function, append

So i'm having problems with append function. It just doesn't add words to the list . What im trying to do is account login , where you can add new account what you can use when you login. This is just an example script put it works the same way. I'm trying to add new word to my mapp (example: Guido) and then i can use that word "guido" to get my program to print yay .
So here's my example script:

```
mapp = ["example"]



example1 = raw_input("Enter Username: ")
if example1 in mapp:
    print "yay"
else:
    print ("Forgot Username eh?")
    example = raw_input("Enter New Username: ")
    if example not in mapp:
        mapp.append(example)
```

So if anybody can help , help is appreciated . Thanks

Comment: How are you checking whether something has been added to the list?

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't work?' What is your expected outcome?

Comment: it's working. what output you want?

Comment: Given what you're doing, you might consider using a ``set`` rather than a ``list``. A set seems to be a more appropriate data structure for your intentions here. Additionally, you can get rid of the ``if example not in map`` check. To use it, update your code to ``mapp = set(['example'])``, remove the ``if example not in mapp`` line and change ``append`` to ``add``.

Comment: My expected outcome is what its supposed to do. When you enter the right username what is in mapp the program will print "yay" . So if i add words to the mapp , example "eat" then i can use the word eat to get my program to print yay. I have tested, and it doesn't work

Comment: *My expected outcome is what its supposed to do.* - you say that like it is obvious - we are not mind readers and your code isn't clear. You need to tell us what it is supposed to do if you want help.

Comment: @Lattyware I'm sorry i don't wanna be a douche. But in the same comment i also told what its supposed to do. And what i meant with that is, that code is pretty simple so i thought that advanced python coders would easily understand that. I'm also from finland so my english isn't the best so i'm sorry if i sounded like a douche. But in one thing i have to disagree. You say my code isn't clear. My code is as clear as possible

Comment: And i say this one more time. What i'm trying to do is login-account-password program. This is part of my project. I will do small program wich holds accounts and login system where you can acces the main program. And this is just example script but works the same way. You need to type the right word wich is in mapp to print the word , if you want to create "new account" you can do that and now you should use the new account (word) you just created to print the text. (Of course instead printing text my program will start my main program if the password is correct)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the last line to your script, and see that it is in fact working. (Edited to add a `while` loop that will keep the program running forever).

```
mapp = ["example"]


while True:
    example1 = raw_input("Enter Username: ")
    if example1 in mapp:
        print "yay"
    else:
        print ("Forgot Username eh?")
        example = raw_input("Enter New Username: ")
        if example not in mapp:
            mapp.append(example)

    print mmap
```

Comment: So why i can't use word "example" to get my program to print yay after i have added it to the map .

Comment: Because your program terminates (stops running) when it reaches the end. If you'd like to make it continue, check out my edit above (give me a second)

Answer (score 0):

It does add words (one word, because you only do it once) to the list. Add `print mapp` to the end and you'll see.